# Format SanDisk Extreme Pro SSD V2 on Mac

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, apfs, disk-format, macos

**Formatting** (erasing) `SanDisk Extreme Pro 55AF Media` works but **looks unusual** in Disk Utility (image):

Erase: SanDisk Extreme Pro 55AF Media

```
Name: SD
Format: APFS
Scheme: GUID Partition Map
```

Result: `SanDisk Extreme Pro 55AF Media` > `Container disk5` > `SD`

[image]

*macOS Monterey, Intel

```
/dev/disk4 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk4
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     209.7 MB   disk4s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk5⁩         2.0 TB     disk4s2

/dev/disk5 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +2.0 TB     disk5
                                 Physical Store disk4s2
   1:                APFS Volume ⁨SD⁩                      753.7 KB   disk5s1
```

Comment: What is the output of `diskutil list`?

Comment: @lhf just updated the post